# How to find the CPU and Memory Usage of a Process in Mac OS X using Valgrind ?

Tags: macos, memory-management, valgrind, cpu-usage

Is there a specific tool in Valgrind which can be used to find the CPU and Memory usage of a given process ? I went through the tool given in http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html . Just not sure which tool to use for CPU and Memory Profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Use the massif tool to get memory-usage information. I am not sure what you mean by "CPU usage", what exactly do you want to profile? If you want to know how many chache-hits/misses you are having cachegrind is the right tool for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. I just want to know how much % of the CPU the program is using. Like we get in 'top' command.

Comment: AFAIR there is no tool in valgrind which will do something like this - the % of CPU usage is a symptom of many different things. The valgrind tools analyse "simpler" things, like the number of L1/L2 misses, which also have an impact on cpu utilization.